# Remove Object From Array if the value is empty in name and value pair js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
[{name: "mode", value: "1"},{name: "group", value: ""},{name: "from_date", value: ""},{name: "to_date", value: "2018-10-16"},{name: "action", value: "ac_filter_transactions"}
```

This is how my array looks like. I want to remove the name and value pair from the array if the `value` is empty.

I tried this solution: but this didn't work

```
formData.map((i) => {
  (i.value == "") ? delete i: "";
});
```

I know this is a simple question but I couldn't find any relevant example to solve this problem. All examples and solutions I found was for this type of object

```
let obj = {"firstname": "XYZ", "lastname": "ABC"}
```

What are the difference between both the objects?

Comment: sounds like a good use case for `Array.filter`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and return entries based on a boolean of whether or not the `value` exists since an empty string is falsy.

```
a.filter(o => (o.value));
```

```js
let a = [{name: "mode", value: "1"},{name: "group", value: ""},{name: "from_date", value: ""},{name: "to_date", value: "2018-10-16"},{name: "action", value: "ac_filter_transactions"}];


let result = a.filter(o => (o.value));

console.log(result);
```

**Note**: If the any of your `value` properties are also falsy, they won't be picked up either. To get around this you could simply rewrite it using: `(o.value !== "")`

```js
let a = [{name: "mode", value: "1"},{name: "group", value: ""},{name: "from_date", value: ""},{name: "to_date", value: "2018-10-16"},{name: "action", value: "ac_filter_transactions"}];


let result = a.filter(o => (o.value !== ""));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Re: Note; did you mean to write `!==` instead of `!=`. The `x != ""` filter still filters out `false`, `null`, `0`, `undefined` etc.

Answer (score 2):

For your question title I assume "remove" means mutate the array (change its actual content). If it is so you can do it like this:

```
const copy = arr.slice(); // copy of array for iterating without getting the index (`i`) wrong
let count = 0;
copy.forEach((val, i) => { if (!val.value) arr.splice(i - count++, 1); });
                      // maybe `val.value != ""` instead of `!val.value` ?
```

Demo:

```js
var arr = [{name: "mode",value: "1"}, {name: "group", value: ""}, {name: "from_date",value: ""}, {name: "to_date", value: "2018-10-16"}, {name: "action",value:"ac_filter_transactions"}];

const copy = arr.slice();
let count = 0;
copy.forEach((val, i) => { if (!val.value) arr.splice(i - count++, 1); });
console.log(arr); // print original array, not a copy
```

---

Or if you do not want to mutate the array (do not change its actual content) then you  can just make a (filtered) copy of it like this:

```
const copy = arr.filter(val => !!val.value)
```

Demo:

```js
var arr = [{name: "mode",value: "1"}, {name: "group", value: ""}, {name: "from_date",value: ""}, {name: "to_date", value: "2018-10-16"}, {name: "action",value:"ac_filter_transactions"}];

console.log(arr.filter(val => !!val.value)); // print a copy, not the original array
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.map will return the same number of items in a new array. So, you would need to use Array.reduce instead.

```
formData.reduce((result, item) => {
  if (item.value) {
    result.push(item);
  }

  return result;
}, []);
```